# What are curves that doesn't have unit-speed reparametrization?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

The following is a proposition (Proposition 1.3.6) from Pressley's Elementary Differential Geometry.

> Proposition: A parametrized curve has a unit-speed reparametrization if and only if it is regular.

My question is that, **what are curves that does not have unit-speed reparametrization?** One obvious candidate is the constant curve as they are not regular. Are there any other such curves?

Comment: You know that these are the non-regular curves. So what remains open? Examples?

Comment: The constant curves? Some reparametrizations which have a vanishing tangent vector at some point -- these are basically non-regular curves. I'm not sure of others.

Comment: A differentiable curve is regular if its derivative never vanishes. Thus a non-regular curve is one whose derivative vanishes at least at one point. **These are precisely the curves that do not have a unit-speed reparametrization.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$

$$ t \mapsto (t^2, t^3) $$

which forms a cusp. It does not have a unit speed reparametrization (it doesn't even have a tangent vector when $t = 0$).

Comment: So I'm guessing that they are curves which has a vanishing tangent vector at some point?

Comment: @devianceee: this is a point where it pays to be careful to distinguish between a curve and its parametrization. When we talk about a regular curve we talk about a curve together with a specific parametrization. And regularity is precisely that the tangent vector doesn't vanish. // Now, it is however possible for a irregular curve to have an image that coincides with that of a regular curve; think about the curve $t \mapsto (t^3, t^3)$.

Comment: That is really insightful, I was always confused between a curve and its parametrization. I find it a bit paradoxical that a curve can be both regular and irregular. I know it is true by the example you gave. However, if a parametrized curve is regular, then there is a unit speed reparametrization. But, if we take a non-unit speed reparametrization, then the parametrized curve is not regular. So, will it always be the case that if a curve is regular, then it can always have the possibility to be irregular (by a different parametrization) but not the other way around?

Comment: @devianceee: usually when we talk about "reparametrization" we require the transition function between the two parametrizations be itself regular (i.e. having no critical points). In this sense _all_ reparametrizations of an irregularly parametrized curve will be irregular, and _all_ reparametrizations of an regularly parametrized curve will be regular.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Excellent explanation thanks!